# How to block internet access for a VM guest? (but keep LAN to host)

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, opensuse, libvirt, virt-manager

I'm using Virtual Machine Manager i.e. `libvirt` and `virt-manager` to run a Windows 10 on openSUSE Leap 15.4. The network config is:

[image: Screenshot: network config]

This config provides the Internet access on guest whenever there is any Internet connection on host.

I need to have the Internet connection on **host**. But I need to block the Internet access on **guest**. I need to do something like [this post](https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/528416-How-to-block-internet-access-for-a-VM-guest-(but-keep-LAN-to-host)). But that post doesn't mention how the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

This answer was not made on openSUSE but there should be no difference whatever distribution the *virt-manager* client is running on (nor *libvirtd*, since this can be done remotely).

You have to create a new libvirt network in [Isolated mode](https://wiki.libvirt.org/VirtualNetworking.html#isolated-mode):

> Isolated mode
>
> In this mode, guests connected to the virtual switch can communicate
> with each other, and with the host. However, their traffic will not
> pass outside of the host, nor can they receive traffic from outside
> the host.
>
> [image: Virtual switch: Isolated mode]

For this, all done using the *virt-manager* GUI:

- right-click on the QEMU/KVM (not on a VM inside this) connection, and use *Details*.

  [image: Connection Details]
- In the new window switch to the *Virtual Networks* tab

  There should probably be a single network: *default* which is the default NAT network.
- Click on the `+` button at the bottom to create a new network

  [image: Add Network]

  - Use a relevant name for the new network. Eg: `hostonly`.
  - Change the mode to `Isolated`

    [image: Create virtual network]
  - Ensure that the chosen IPv4 network is not already used by an other network setting

    This should not happen the first time, but possibly might when multiple other networks are created. If needed, change the network address offered by default.
- Go to the VM's settings and change the NIC's network to the newly created network

  [image: Network source]

  This can be done at VM/NIC's creation or as a setting change.

  If done while the VM is running, for immediate effect you should also temporarily disconnect the virtual NIC (uncheck *Link state*), apply, and reconnect it (check *Link state*) , re-apply, to trigger a reconfiguration of the network in the VM's OS (else it won't notice until a DHCP lease refresh is due, possibly hours later).

Comment: I don't have the opportunity to double-check your approach. I will as soon as I have the time. Thanks.